# Flask-Whooshee returning no results

Tags: flask, flask-whooshee

I've been working on trying to integrate some form of full text search to a small assignment (for fun). Unfortunately, no matter the search term, it returns no results, not even when I enter exact information.

For example, when I perform a search using the Python console after importing the SQLAlchemy model, it returns information just as expected.

```
>>> Contact.query.whooshee_search('sch').all()
[<Contact u'Kimberley' u'Schuppe' u'cathie.schmitt@paucek.com'>, <Contact u'Kelsey' u'Schinner' u'walsh.ardyce@yahoo.com'>, <Contact u'Rella' u'Schamberger' u'abbott.feest@gmail.com'>]
```

However, when performing the same search through the Flask view from a POST parameter it returns with nothing.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/page/<int:page>', methods=['GET'])
def index(page=1):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = request.form['search']
        result = Contact.query.whooshee_search(query).all()
        print query, 'result:', result
    contact = Contact.query.with_entities(Contact.lname, Contact.fname, Contact.phone, Contact.addr, Contact.email).paginate(page, app.config['PAGE_MAX'], False)
    return render_template('index.html', entry=contact)
```

Result from search of 'sch' from form:

```
sch result: []
```

What could be causing this? I'm genuinely stumped why the same query from the console works fine, but through the view returns nothing.

Comment: Battleroid were you able to find a solution? I think I'm getting the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I eventually just moved from SQLite to MySQL. That seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: Really? how were you able to get whooshee to understand your partial search (ngram search?)? It keeps making me use a full text with no error to get it correctly.

Comment: I honestly can't remember. I ended up dropping full text search as it wasn't needed anyway.

Comment: Make sure to include the `WHOOSHEE_DIR` in your app.config .  I had accidentally only specified the path in my production config and not development and was having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old but just in case anyone is facing a similar issue:

Flask-Whooshee (and other flask whoosh variants) seem to work by adding to the index when new data is added to the db, so if you have an existing app or a db which already contains data then the index will be empty.

Only data that is added *after* the index is created will be indexed.

If you do have an existing app/db then Flask-Whooshee includes the `Whooshee.reindex()` method to index the data. Note that this needs to be called after any models have been registered, so in the case where you are defining models in a separate file, the `__init__.py` file would look something like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
whooshee = Whooshee(app)

from app import models

with app.app_context():
    whooshee.reindex()
```